# Google Account in Online Accounts is blank from the start in Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: sync, google, 18.10, online-accounts

[Blank Google Window-Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8yxn.jpg)I've read threads about how after people type in their email and password, if they have 2 step verification, have a blank window when getting to the verification window.  However, that is not my problem.  My problem is that the google account window is completely blank from the get go.  I see it trying to search google as the blue bar on top goes across the screen.  I can even hover over the area where I think the email is, as the cursor changes to indicate a text entry, and enter it, and then I can hover over the area where I think the password is and enter it and my google app on my phone will prompt me to verify the login attempt, which I then do, the bar on top goes accross and I see the window processing the approval but I can't get any farther.  I guess where the blue ok button should be as the cursor changes in the right location to a hand pointer but I can't get any further as clicking where I think the blue ok button would be doesn't do anything, nor does scrolling down.  So the point is that it is processing the email and password and even the 2 step verification, but I'm doing it blindly as the window is always blank.

** UPDATE 10-31-18 **
BTW, I have duplicated this problem accross several linux distro's.  I see it on Linux Mint and oddly in Fedora 28.  The same exact problem.  When opening the google account, I see it processing the info and expect google to display the login info, but it's blank.  But if I hover over the correct areas I can guess where to put in the email address because the cursor changes from an arrow to a cursor and if I hit  enter, I can guess where to put in the password, and it will send me the link to approve, due to 2 step verification, on my google app on my iphone which I can then approve.  But that's as far as I can take it without seeing any further info.

Comment: 4 years later the problem persists

Answer (score 6):

As a workaround, you can start gnome-control-center with compositing disabled with:

```
WEBKIT_DISABLE_COMPOSITING_MODE=1 gnome-control-center
```

as esplained [here](https://blogs.gnome.org/mcatanzaro/2018/11/06/mesa-update-breaks-webkitgtk-in-fedora-29/)

Comment: This worked for me in Ubuntu 20.04. Thanks.